# Query to combine records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a **chain**  model that has many **facilities**

I have a **company** model has many **company_mappings**. Through **company_mappings** a **comapny** can have many facilities either through *chains* or directly from a *facility*, both of them through a polymorphic association in the **companies_mapping** model.

The **Company_Mapping** Model

```
belongs_to :company
belongs_to :company_associations, polymorphic: true
```

The **Chain** Model

```
has_many :company_mappings, as: :company_associations
has_many :facilities
```

The **Facility** Model

```
has_many :company_mappings, as: :company_associations
belongs_to :chain
```

Now i have the company model has two different queries to get its assoiciated facilities. I would like to have one query that fetches all *facilities* associated from a company

The **company** model

```
has_many :company_mappings
has_many :chains, through: :company_mappings, source: :company_associations, source_type: "Chain"
has_many :facilities, through: :company_mappings, source: :company_associations, source_type: "Facility"
has_many :facilities_from_chains, through: :chains,source: :facilities, class_name: 'Facility'
```

I would like to combine *facilities* and _facilities_from_chains_ into a single query or able to somehow merge them. I tried using *.merge* but that gives an error.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be to provide an instance method which queried both relations separately, fetched the results and combined them. Try adding this to your company model:

```
def all_facilities
  facilities + facilities_from_chains
end
```

Combining the results together into a single array like this will cause your results to be converted from a relation object (which you could call further `.where` clauses on for example) to an array which you cannot chain further AR statements to. It's worth keeping that in mind.

There may be another way to do this with a single SQL query, but this seems like the easiest implementation at the potential expense of DB performance.

Comment: thanks @jon, but im looking to get back active record relation. Im trying on my own as well, will post the answer if I can find a way

Answer (score 0):

I found a way just in case somebody what like to know how.

```
  scope :company_facilities, -> (chain_ids,company_id){
    includes(:company_mappings)
      .where("chain_id IN (?) OR (company_mappings.company_associations_type=? and company_mappings.company_id=?)", chain_ids , "Facility", company_id)
      .references(:company_mappings)
  }
```

The idea is to include *Company_Mapping* which would do a left outer join. Then for each facility record find if it is part of any of the chain the *Company* is associated to **else** if its company_mappings.company_id equals to calling Company's id.